# How to use Postgresql or MySQL database offline on Android?

Tags: android, mysql, database, postgresql, database-connection

I am looking for a way to use either PostgreSQL or MySQL (I am using the former, but I could just find a way to export it to MySQL and use that one) database offline.

I need to be able to query a database offline on an Android device.

Is it possible? Using JDBC it should be possible, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by "offline"?  Do you mean that the DBMS resides locally on your Android device?

Comment: I am producing an application. I want some information to be available offline (without internet connection). The simplest way to use the same queries but being offline.

Comment: And what process will be executing those queries?  Are you proposing installing a MySQL server on your Android device?

Comment: That's the problem. I want to release this application, what would you suggest to use? I need something that resembles the use of a DBMS, in terms of speed and ease of use.

Comment: In that case, I believe the standard solution for Android is SQLite databases: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: Thanks, this seems a good way ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) . It is available out-of-the-box, and supported since version 1.